# Switching multi languages issue

Tags: php, translation

I can switch language of website in French to English and English to French by clicking same link. But the issue is, I need to press twice on the link before getting a good result. I have added this to header.php file:

```
<li>
  <?php if(isset($_GET['lang'])and $_GET['lang']=='en'){
      echo '<a href="index.php?lang=fr">Francais</a>';}
    else echo '<a href="index.php?lang=en">English</a>'; ?>
</li>
```

This is for switch language to french if we click to Francais Or switch to English when click on English. And it works. The problem is we have to click twice on the link to change language. That is not normal. How can i fix it?

Here is the first url when I sign in to Xibo: `http://myIP_adress/Xibo/` (this shows up main menu interface with English icon at the top, next to the logout icon). And text is in English.

If I press on English icon, I get this url: `http://myIP_adress/Xibo/index.php?lang=en` ( Now English icon switch to Francais icon and text still in English )

If I press on Francais icon to text in French, I get this url: `http://myIP_adress/Xibo/index.php?lang=fr&lang=en` (still get Francais icon and text still in English)

if I press on francais icon again, I get this url `http://myIP_adress/Xibo/index.php?lang=fr&lang=fr` (now Francais icon switch to English icon and text is in french, So it respond as i expect it). From here, I have to press 2 times to English icon to get expected responding (Francais icon and text in English).

Comment: that's kinda strange. are you using javascript?

Comment: If you get `index.php?lang=fr&lang=en` in your url there must be someting else that's causing this.

Comment: If you can add the url where this can be seen in action. Something *is* adding the parameter twice. You talk about an icon, but the links in the code-example are text-links. Are there additional links probably?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths and not relative paths. Right now your path gets added to whatever the browsers sees as the base URL.

```
$path = '/Xibo/index.php';
echo '<a href="'.$path.'?lang=fr">Francais</a>';}
```

Comment: Using this $path doesnèt change anything....I tried it but still have same problem.

Comment: Seems to be some problem with this Xibo application. Under pure php this should definitely work. Add Xibo to your tags to get it listed there as well. Dunno though if that tag even exists